# Developing on a remote machine and Git - Best Practices

Tags: python, git, pytorch, cloud

I've been developing software systems that generally end up training large scale models and then evaluating them on a number of remote cloud instances, for the past 6 years. I am using primarily Python and PyTorch as the main two components of my projects.

Recently, I adopted a very strong git commit ethic with proper messaging formats etc, and been using continual integration to develop large open source projects.

What has become increasingly clear is that using Git as a means of 'uploading' code to the cloud is not the best way of syncing my repo, since that leaves a trail of rubbish commit messages etc. I have also tried using something like Pycharm's remote syncing functionality, but unfortunately that means that my code only leaves on a volatile remote machine and a volatile local machine.

I am wondering, is there a proper way to use Git as a syncing agent and a development tracking agent? Is my way of doing things completely stupid here?

Just looking to hear what other people do out there. Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

(This question seems more suitable for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

I'd use rsync to synchronize the executable code to the remote machine that executes, while using git only for code revision control. If necessary, I'd set up another remote machine to store the canonical main branch as a backup, or as a repository to share the code with colleagues. I may want to use tags (not branches) to tie a certain result to the code that reproduces it. And I'd probably need a separate notebook (could be a spreadsheet) that explains what and why I did the change in that tag (though git notes seems handy for that too).